# Are there any 32-bit version for ubuntu server 13.04?

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit

Are there any 32-bit version for ubuntu server 13.04? Since I can only download 64-bit version from ubuntu.com

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get it from [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-server-i386.iso).

Answer (score 1):

Complete list of download options are available [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads).

Answer (score 1):

For complete technical details on Raring Ringtail **13.04**:

[Ubuntu Wiki >> Raring Ringtail - release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RaringRingtail/ReleaseNotes)

---

Directly download ALL variants from:

[Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring Ringtail) >> Select an image](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/)

> **Server install image**
>
> The server install image allows you to install Ubuntu permanently on a computer for use as a server. It will not install a graphical user interface.
>
> There are three images available, each for a different type of computer:
>
> **PC (Intel x86) server install image**
>
> > For almost all PCs. This includes most machines with Intel/AMD/etc type processors and almost all computers that run Microsoft Windows, as well as newer Apple Macintosh systems based on Intel processors. Choose this if you are at all unsure.
>
> **64-bit PC (AMD64) server install image**
>
> > Choose this to take full advantage of computers based on the AMD64 or EM64T architecture (e.g., Athlon64, Opteron, EM64T Xeon, Core 2). If you have a non-64-bit processor made by AMD, or if you need full support for 32-bit code, use the Intel x86 images instead.
>
> **64-bit Mac (AMD64) server install image**
>
> > Choose this to take full advantage of computers based on the AMD64 or EM64T architecture (e.g., Athlon64, Opteron, EM64T Xeon, Core 2). If you have a non-64-bit processor made by AMD, or if you need full support for 32-bit code, use the Intel x86 images instead. This image is adjusted to work properly on Mac systems.